# Beautiful soup - find_all function is returning returning only 20 items from the page. The actual results are around 250

Tags: html, beautifulsoup

I am using find_all in beautiful soup library to parse the HTML text.

code

```
headers = ({'User-Agent':
            'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'})

URL = "https://housing.com/in/buy/searches/M1Pmp1mc1ak4wflhbs_735yq6kvim3c7hqz_3g8uxzo18sqqdcuwU2yr9t"
response = get(URL, headers=headers)

html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

len(html_soup)
```

This is returning only 20 items even though the page shows 250 results. What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try (This takes all (291)):

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='c:/program/geckodriver.exe')

URL = "https://housing.com/in/buy/searches/M1Pmp1mc1ak4wflhbs_735yq6kvim3c7hqz_3g8uxzo18sqqdcuwU2yr9t"
driver.get(URL)

driver.maximize_window()

PAUSE_TIME = 2


lh = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

while True:

    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(PAUSE_TIME)
    nh = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if nh == lh:
        break
    lh = nh
articles = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.css-h7k7mr')

for article in articles:
    print(article.text)
    print('-' * 80)

driver.close()
```

prints:

```
₹45.11 L
EMI starts at ₹28.13 K
3 BHK Apartment
Bachupally, Nizampet, Hyderabad
Build Up Area
1556 sq.ft
Avg. Price
₹2.90 K/sq.ft
Special Highlights
24x7 Security
Badminton Court
Cycling & Jogging Track
Gated Community
3 BHK Apartment available for sale in Bachapally,hyderabad,beside Mama Medical College, Nizampet, Hyderabad. Available amenities are: Gym, Swimming pool, Garden, Kids area, Sports facility, Lift. Apartment has 3 bedroom, 2 bathroom.
Read more
M Srikanth
Housing Prime Agent
Contact
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
₹37.96 L - 62.05 L
EMI starts at ₹23.67 K
Bhuvanteza Evk Aura
Marketed by Sri Avani Infra Projects
Kollur, Hyderabad
Configurations
2, 3 BHK Apartments
Possession Starts
Nov, 2022
Avg. Price
₹3.65 K/sq.ft
Real estate developer Bhuvanteza Infrastructures has launched prime housing project Evk Aura in Kollur, Hyderabad. The project is offering beautiful and comfortable 2 and 3 BHK apartments for sale. Built-up area for 2 BHK apartments is in the range of 1040 to 1185 sq ft. and for 3 BHK apartments it is 1700 sq ft. Amenities which are required for a comfortable living will be available in the complex, they are car parking, club house, swimming pool, children play area, power backup and others. Developer Bhuvanteza Infrastructures can be contacted for owning an apartment in Evk Aura. Kollur is a ...
Read more
SA
Sri Avani Infra Projects
Seller
Contact
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and so on....

**Note selenium**: You need [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) and [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and in this code geckodriver is set to be imported from `c:/program/geckodriver.exe`

Answer (score 0):

you're not reading right, there are 250 results in total but only 20 are shown, that's why you get 20 in python

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It looks like html_soup is only extracting 20 items in the list.